# Has Season 8 been co-written by both GRRM and D&D or just by D&D?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The *A Song of Ice and Fire* books currently end at when Jon is killed (if I'm not wrong - and I don't know if new ones came out). But the *Game of Thrones* TV-show supercedes the books.

So is the script for the show (everything after Jon is killed) written by just Benioff and Weiss or is GRR Martin (author of the books that inspired the show) involved in the script writing and the way the show shapes?

Specifically season 8 - is GRRM also involved in writing the show script with D&D?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears he is not. From [this](https://mashable.com/2017/03/12/game-of-thrones-season-8-6-episodes/#4sPVzApfimqw) Mashable Article:

> "Dave Hill will write the season premiere, Brian Cogman will write 802
>   and then we'll write the other four," Benioff continued. "Dan and I
>   just pick halves; we fight over who gets to write which half, who gets
>   to kill Sansa ..."

It seems like [GRRM used to help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones#Writing) in the writing of the show, but not anymore:

> A Song of Ice and Fire author George R. R. Martin wrote one episode in
>   each of the first four seasons. Martin did not write an episode for
>   the later seasons, since he wanted to focus on completing the sixth
>   novel (The Winds of Winter).